# SQL SELECT * FROM datetime = CURDATE() return an empty result set

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Can anyone tell me where's my mistake? By using that query, it should return some rows where the data have datetime = '2012-10-12' right? Here is my [reference](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=37878)

My datetime column = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS', data type = datetime.

I am using XAMPP v1.8.0, MySQL v5.5.25a.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `CAST`ing `datetime` to `date` by using `DATE()`

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableName
WHERE DATE(`datetime`) = DATE(CURDATE())
```

`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` is not equal to `YYYY-MM-DD`

```
2012-01-01 12:12:12 is not equal to 2012-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks, I am sorry i am missing the datetime casting.

Comment: @JohnWoo, +1.  No need to DATE()-coerce CURDATE(), however, it's already a DATE type.  Also, `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` does equal `YYYY-MM-DD`, but only at `00:00:00` (the DATE is promoted to a DATETIME).

Answer (score 6):

Do not use functions on your columns, e.g. `DATE(datetime)` - mysql can't use your index.

It's almost certainly better to use a range:

```
WHERE `datetime` between '2012-01-01 00:00:00' and '2012-01-01 23:59:59'
```

or store just the DATE portion in a separate column (which will have lower cardinality and be better treated by the optimizer).

Comment: This is still very important to consider! On big databases this may speed up your query by much more than a hundred times! This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE DATE(datetime) = CURDATE()
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

use `DATE()` from mysql to format the TIMESTAMP to DATE

`Select * FROM tablename WHERE DATE(colname) = CURDATE()`